# Can I transform InDesign guidelines, rectangle frame tools and other guidelines into vectors?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, vector, guides

I haven't been able to find any information or guide whatsoever to see whether it was possible to transform InDesign guides into vector lines. I am aware that doing this on Illustrator would've been a lot more easier, which I am trying to do.

On another note, perhaps let's say to have my baseline printed out as well.

Funny enough the print baseline option wasn't available/greyed out when I tried, so it's kind of annoying.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Export to PDF and tick to include 'Visibile Guides and Baseline Grids' and 'Non-Printing Objects'. This will generate a PDF with the guides and document grid converted to normal lines, which you can then open in Illustrator and further customize as an AI file, which can then be linked back into InDesign if needed.